# How to implement cookies consent in ReactJS/HTML/CSS website with ability to turn cookies off?

Tags: reactjs, cookies, setcookie

I am working on a website and we currently have a cookie banner which displays on launch and has a ok button. However I would to change this to give users the options to turn on/off the cookie categories they wish to be tracked. Something like this:

[image: example of cookie banner]

I am new to reactjs, I have looked online for libraries or sample but cannot find something, but I am sure they will be plenty. Anyone help or guidance will be appreciated.

I have thought of adding each type of cookie to a specific group and create a function which then is called from front-end but if there is already a solution out there, it'll save time and I am worried about cross-browser/device support as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you use functional components, a dependency-free way to implement a cookies consent banner as you described (with user able to set and update cookies preferences) in React is using Context and Hooks, as detailed in this article: https://daankauwenberg.com/react-cookie-consent/

Comment: This URL is not working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [react-cookie](https://github.com/reactivestack/cookies/tree/master/packages/react-cookie) package for this.

and then use relevant methods for it.
Ex, if the user agrees to save the cookie setCookie will be called.

Comment: Thanks, I had a look at the article and trying to implement this. Would you know if there is any video tutorial of this being implemented. I am completely new and struggling a little. The site already sets cookies including Facebook and google analytics for which I need to provide the option to toggle on/off. Currently, the site is using react-cookie-consent npm. Thanks.